# ChromePhp make it as global var to work in all my pages

Tags: php, google-chrome

[ChromePHP](http://www.chromephp.com/) is a php class that allow you to do php logs in javascript console.

i have installed the chrome extention ChromePHP, it's activated

i was trying to do this:

**config.php**:

```
    include_once ('ChromePhp.php');

    $trace = new ChromePhp();
```

**myClass.php**:

```
     include_once ('config.php');
     $trace->log("test");
```

but it's not working some help please

i get :`** Fatal error: Call to private ChromePhp::__construct() from invalid context in C:\wamp\www\partenariat\autres\config.php on line 11**`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [constructor](https://github.com/ccampbell/chromephp/blob/master/ChromePhp.php#L156) is private, so you can't use `new` on it.  To get an object, you need to use ChromePhp's [`getInstance`](https://github.com/ccampbell/chromephp/blob/master/ChromePhp.php#L169) method.

```
$trace = ChromePhp::getInstance();
```